# sqlite3 - using record of another table in GLOB

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can we use the content of a record from another table(within the same file) in a GLOB statement?

Let's say we have two tables; `tableA` and `tableB` and what I want is executing a query which has `glob` in it and in that `glob` function, I want to concatenate the value of a row from `tableB` with some text; something like:(which obviously is not working!)

```
select * from tableA where columnA glob(tableB.rowid=3 || 'some text')
```

`**tableB.rowid=3**`: content of a record from tableB where it's rowid=3

If such a thing is possible, how to express it in the proper way?

**[Update 1]:**

Because of some inherent technical issues, I can't save the content of that other table(`tableB.rowid=3`) into a variable and use it with the second query(in another programming environment out of SQLite itself I mean); I just want to know if such a thing is possible within SQLite or not;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up a single value can be done with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE ColumnA GLOB (SELECT GlobPatternColumn
                    FROM TableB
                    WHERE rowid = 3) || 'some text'
```

Comment: I wonder if sqlite has the ability to declare variables so that I put the result of subquery in it and use it later?